# How do I compare two dates and times in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

### Heading

In my problem, I have four different inputs making up two time intervals i.e. From --> To.
"From" has a date input and a time input

```
<Input
  type="date"
  value={fromDate}
  onChange={(e) => setFromDate(e.target.value)}
>
<Input
  type="time"
  value={fromTime}
  onChange={(e) => setFromTime(e.target.value)}
>
```

Exactly same "To" interval inputs. Now I want to filter a list having date format as this:

'2022-10-10T12:10:49.000000Z'

[image]

Now how do I compare my input date and time altogether with this above string?

Comment: We need to know what the list is.

Comment: List is just an array of JS object fetched from backend, each object has a value of date mentioned above. Just want to compare my inputs with the value.

Comment: So you can use `new Date('2022-10-10T12:10:49.000000Z');` on a string of that format to create a Date object for each date you have in a list. To compare two Date objects, you can simply use the `>` operator on them. Does this help, or have I missed part of your question?

Comment: Show example data. Good questions have input and expected output.

Comment: @AidanWansbrough yup it helped, combined the date and time of inputs and converted it to date object to compare. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can compare them in some way like below:

```
const date1 = new Date(firstDateInterval)
const date2 = new Date(secondDateInterval)

if(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()){
  // do something
}
```